# load cookie to html field jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I want to load a cookie value directly to all html field with an specific class when the page is loaded. I have a cookie created with the same name as the field's id.

Doing this does not work.

```
$(".class").val(function(){
    el=$(this);
    id=el.attr("id");
    cookie_val=$.cookie(id);
    el.val(cookie_val);
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing a function to [jQuery's `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method, the desired value should be returned by the function.

As your code stands, your function is being run which does set the value. It then returns `undefined`, however, which sets it to empty.

This should work:

```
$('.class').val(function () {
    return $.cookie($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `.each()` to have your function do the value setting without needing to return:

```
$('.class').each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.val($.cookie(el.attr('id')));
});
```

FWIW, I wrote a cookies library which provides jQuery plugins for this very functionality (fill a field with the value held by a cookie of the same name).

Answer (score 0):

here´s a function you can send the parameter/cookiename and return value

```
function findnameGetvalue(n){
    a = document.cookie;
    while(a != ''){
        cookiename = a.substring(0,a.search('='));
        cookievalue = a.substring(a.search('=')+1,a.search(';'));
        if(cookievalue == cookiename+'='){
            cookievalue = a.substring(a.search('=')+1,a.length);
        }
        if(cookiename == n){ // if found return value
            return cookievalue;
        }
        i = a.search(';');
        if(i == -1){ // not found do stuff
            i = a.length
        }
        else{
            i += 2;
        }
        a = a.substring(i,a.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: The user is already using a cookie library ( https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie ) for accessing the cookie value.

Comment: ah okay i just saw this and thought alright, whatever he´s doing i have a solution